# Sorting Lists into Alphabetical Order

Tags: python

I have a list which I want to sort into alphabetical order, but it is not working. I have written this, but it does not work very well:

```
#!usr/bin/python
f = open("test.txt","r") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
myList = []
for line in f:
    myList.append(line)
f.close()
print myList
subList = []

for i in range(1, len(myList)):
    print myList[i]
    subList.append(myList[i])

subList.sort()
print subList
```

This is the text file:

```
Test List
ball
apple
cat
digger
elephant
```

and this is the output:

```
Enigmatist:PYTHON lbligh$ python test.py
['Test List\n', 'ball\n', 'apple\n', 'cat\n', 'digger\n', 'elephant']
ball

apple

cat

digger

elephant
['apple\n', 'ball\n', 'cat\n', 'digger\n', 'elephant']
```

Any troubleshooting would be extremely helpful. Thanks

N.B. I am using python 2.7.9

Comment: Please explain what is not working? Your output seems to be in sorted order.

Comment: The output is sorted, though

Comment: It is supposed to sort it, then replace the items in the file with the sorted data

Comment: @LukeBligh then you'll have to write code to re-write the file! You haven't done that step yet :)

Comment: Yeah, Id like to know how to replace all the items except the first, with the sorted data. That was what I was having trouble with, so I posted the last peice of code that was working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just forgotten to overwrite the file, that's all.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as inf:
    lst = inf.readlines()  # much easier than iterating and accumulating

lst[1:] = sorted(lst[1:])  # this will leave the first line: "Test List" intact

with open('test.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.writelines(lst)  # re-write the file
```

Comment: I added this at the end, and got this:                                                         ['Test List\n', 'ball\n', 'apple\n', 'cat\n', 'digger\n', 'elephant\n']
ball

apple

cat

digger

elephant

['apple\n', 'ball\n', 'cat\n', 'digger\n', 'elephant\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nest copy.py", line 17, in <module>
    lst = f.readlines()  # much easier than iterating and accumulating
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Sorry, being stupid and misinterpreted what you meant. All works fine, except I thing you meant "inf", not "f" in "lst = f.readlines()"

Comment: @LukeBligh oops, yep. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out:**

```
f = open("test.txt","r") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
myList = []
for line in f:
    myList.append(line)
f.close()
print myList
subList = []
for i in range(1, len(myList)):
    subList.append(myList[i])

subList.sort()
with open("test.txt","w") as f:
    for x in subList:
        f.write(str(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print(*sorted([i.strip() for i in open('test.txt', 'r')], key=lambda x: x.lower()), file=open('output.txt', 'w'))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that looks like you're taking part in a Python obfuscation contest.

Comment: @Matthias I love Python of the such things. It is fun.